# What is the justification for the type of unfoldr in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, unfold

The example given in the documentation of [`unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr):

```
unfoldr (\b -> if b == 0 then Nothing else Just (b, b-1)) 10
```

can easily be written with a redundant pair:

```
unfoldr (\b -> if b == 1 then Nothing else Just (b-1, b-1)) 11
```

What does `unfoldr` need the pair `(a,b)` for? Why is its type not `(a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]`?

Comment: @jwodder, both fragments result in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] when I test in ghci...

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652452/what-is-the-correct-definition-of-unfold-for-an-untagged-tree/28653008)

Answer (score 14):

A function with type

```
(a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]
```

restricts the output list element type to be the same as the state which is threaded through the generation process. `unfoldr` is more general in that it allows an independent type of state to be used.

Comment: The question I have is whether this theoretically more general type serves any practical purpose or not and if yes if you can give a good example. Certainly the standard example does not make the usefulness of the more elaborate type apparent, as I showed in my question.

Comment: @hkBst Replace `Just (b, b-1)` with `Just (show b, b-1)`.

Comment: @hkBst A more useful example is: `repeat n x = unfoldr (\b -> if b == 0 then Nothing else Just (x, b-1)) n`.  The type of `repeat` is `Int -> a -> [a]`, so that `repeat 5 1 == [1,1,1,1,1]` but also `repeat 5 'a' == "aaaaa"`.   With your version of `unfoldr` you cannot implement `repeat` as a simple call to `unfoldr`.

Answer (score 5):

Leveraging a bit of theory, one can recover the types for folds/unfolds of a recursive type, including lists, understanding why they are what they are.

Let `A` be a fixed type. The type "list of `A`s" satisfies the isomorphism

```
List ~~ Either () (A, List)
```

which can be read "a list value is either a special value (the empty list), or a value of type `A` followed by a list value".

In a more succinct notation we could write `Either` as an infix `+`:

```
List ~~ () + (A, List)
```

Now, if we let `F b = () + (A, b)`, we have that

```
List ~~ F List
```

The above is a fixed point equation, which always arises when using recursive types. For any recursive type defined by `T ~~ F T` we can 
derive the type of the related folds/unfolds (also known as `cata/ana` or induction/coinduction principles)

```
fold   :: (F b -> b) -> T -> b
unfold :: (b -> F b) -> b -> T
```

In the case of lists, we then obtain

```
fold    :: ((() + (A, b)) -> b) -> List -> b
unfoldr :: (b -> (() + (A, b))) -> b -> List
```

The unfold can also be rewritten noting that `Maybe c ~~ () + c`:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (A, b)) -> b -> List
```

The fold can instead be rewritten using

```
((x + y) -> z) ~~ (x -> z, y -> z)
```

getting

```
foldr :: (() -> b, (A, b) -> b) -> List -> b
```

then, since `() -> b ~~ b`,

```
foldr :: (b, (A, b) -> b) -> List -> b
```

finally, since `(x, y) -> z ~~ x -> y -> z` (currying), we have

```
foldr :: b -> ((A, b) -> b) -> List -> b
```

and again:

```
foldr :: b -> (A -> b -> b) -> List -> b
```

and with a final flip `x -> y -> z ~~ y -> x -> z`:

```
foldr :: (A -> b -> b) -> b -> List -> b
```

---

> How do those types follow from the (co)induction principles?

Domain theory states that least fixed points (`F(T)=T`) coincide with least
prefixed points (`F(T)<=T`), when `F` is monotonic over a certain poset.

The induction principle simple states that, if `T` is the least prefixed point, and `F(U)<=U`, then `T<=U`. (Proof. It is the *least*!. QED.)
In formulae,

```
(F(U) <= U)  ==>  (T <= U)
```

To deal with fixed points over types, we need to switch from posets to categories, which makes everything more complex. Very, very roughly, every `<=` is replaced with some morphism. For instance, `F(U)<=U` now means that there is some morphism `F U -> U`. "Monotonic `F`" means that `F` is a functor (since `a<=b` implying `F(a)<=F(b)` now becomes `(a->b)` implying `F a -> F b`). Prefixed points are F-algebras (`F u -> u`). "Least" becomes "initial". And so on.

Hence the type of fold: (implication is `->` as well)

```
fold   :: (F u -> u) -> (T -> u)
```

Unfold derives from the coinduction principle, which deals with greatest postfix points `T` (which become coalgebras)

```
(U <= F(U)) ==> (U <= T)
```

Comment: Certainly very interesting, but I feel that you have not given enough attention to the part where you introduce the initial types of folds and unfolds. How do those types follow from the (co)induction principles?

Comment: @hkBst True. Edited to shed some light.